# How to add a page in another dll into a window in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I created a new wpf application, with the default MainWindow.xaml,

and I created a new page: Page1.xaml with a button in it.

I want to embed the page in the window, so I tried:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <WpfApplication1:Page1></WpfApplication1:Page1>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Then I got a exception.

I searched here, and got another solution, using

so I tried this:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <Frame Source="Page1.xaml"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

it worked.

But

what if the Page1.xaml is not in current project but in a dll file?

Answer (score 0):

The general template to get resources from another assembly is : `Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component/Subfolder/YourResourceFile.xaml"`

Take a look a this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28VS.85%29.aspx)